# Object name is missing in json string

Tags: java, json

I wanted to create json string like this-

```
{
    "credentials": {
        "name":"abc",
        "password":"pass"
    }
}
```

I have created one Java class with name Credentials with "name" and "password" fields.
I have added name and password values in credentials object. To give one REST call I wanted to send json object/string in body section as mentioned earlier.
But my Json string/object doesn't have credentials name in json string. It's looking like this -

```
{
    "name": "jamal11",
    "password": "5test5@5"
}
```

Below is my code for converting Credentials object into JSON string -

```
credentials.setName(name);
credentials.setPassword(password);

//conversion of RequestParamDto object to JSON 
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String requestParamJson = ow.writeValueAsString(credentials);

//add requestParam string to HttpPost
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestParamJson, "UTF-8"));
```

Am I missing something here? Please help me out.
Thank you!

Comment: You will probably need to create a class that has the credentials object as a field for the label to show up in the json

Comment: or without creating class (just one-time solution) you can wrap credentials object in a map:
`ow.writeValueAsString(Collections.singletonMap("credentials", credentials));`

Comment: where do you imagine the `"credentials"` text should magically come from, if you don't store it anywhere

Comment: @Maciej - Thank you so much! It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a json object put one parameter that key of parameter is "credentials" and the value of parameter is a json array that is a json object in it.
or create a class that has the credentials object as a property for the label to show in the json

```
{
    "credentials": [{
        "name":"abc",
        "password":"pass"
    }]
}
```

Example:

```
class MyInterfaceList {
    @JsonProperty("credentials")
    private List<MyInterface> list;

    public List<MyInterface> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<MyInterface> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

final List<MyInterface> lists = new ArrayList<MyInterface>(4);
lists.add(new MyImpl("abc", "pass"));
MyInterfaceList listHolder = new MyInterfaceList();
listHolder.setList(lists);
final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(listHolder);
```

Object Writer
This is the preferable option. Use a configured ObjectWriter instance to generate the JSON. In particular, we are interested in the withRootName method:

```
final List<MyInterface> lists = new ArrayList<MyInterface>(4);
lists.add(new MyImpl("abc", "pass"));
final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer().withRootName("credentials");
final String json = writer.writeValueAsString(lists);
```

Answer (score 0):

remember to add json jar file into the library of your project

```
JSONObject a = new JSONObject();
a.accumulate("credentials", new JSONObject().put("name", "abc").put("password", "123"));
```